# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.'

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to insert data into my database. I can't find any reason why my affectedResults are 0 and it keeps crashing out giving me a big squiggly on my cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), it says there is a 'Incorrect syntax near '('.' so I have carefully analyzed my sql statement for the past hour and i'm not too sure where the problem is.

```
 private int SendData(string sqlStatement)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);

        int AffectedRecords = 0;
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            AffectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        return AffectedRecords;
    }

 private void InsertData()
    {



        string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Participant (LastName, FirstName, " + ("Country, Gender, IACMember, Rank, SponsorId" +
                                    "VALUES (\'{0}\',\'{1}\',\'{2}\',\'{3}\','{4}',{5}, {6})"),
                                    txtLastName.Text, txtFirstName.Text, cboCountry.SelectedItem, Gender(gender),
                                    (chkMember.Checked), ((txtRank.Text == string.Empty) ? "Null" : txtRank.Text),
                                    ((cboSponsor.Text == "No Sponsor") ? "Null" : cboSponsor.SelectedValue));


       SendData(sql);



    }
```

Comment: Missing closing parenthesys after the list of field, no need to put a \ in front of single quotes. BUT never write sql command in this way. This is an open invitation to any wannabe hacker around. It is so easy to crack you program with Sql Injection

Comment: If you use parameterized SQL you will be able to see the problem more clearly - and your app won't be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @stuartd are you talking about something like  command.Parameters.Add("@name", txtName.text);

Comment: @NickNickerson exactly that, yes.

Comment: .. then then the statement becomes `var sql = "INSERT INTO Participant (LastName, FirstName, Country, Gender, IACMember, Rank, SponsorId VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @Country, @Gender, @IACMember, @Rank, @SponsorId)";` which makes it much easier to see the problem, and you don't have to worry about some putting `Robert'); DROP TABLE Participant ;--` in as one of your values..

Comment: @stuartd Question for you man, can i use Ternary Operator like i can in with  string interpolation?

Comment: Yes, `command.Parameters.Add("@rank", txtRank.Text == string.Empty ? "Null" : txtRank.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert data the simple way? Also you are exposing yourself to `SQL INJECTIONS`. Here is the Method

```
private int InsertData()
    {
        int AffectedRecords = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Participant (LastName, FirstName, Country, Gender, IACMember, Rank, SponsorId) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @Country, @Gender, @IACMember, @Rank, @SponsorId)", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cboCountry.SelectedItem);
                //Your Remaining Fields
                AffectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return AffectedRecords;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried but it says there is an error near the value keyword

Comment: This is still missing the closing `)` at the end of the field list.